# How to access parameters of method being watched in ActiveSupport::Notification instrument?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activesupport

I have been playing around with `ActiveSupport::Notifications` recently and I can't figure out how to get to the parameters of a method run in a block. Let me use an example.

You set up the following instrument.

```
ActiveSupport::Notifications.instrument('render', extra: :information) do
  render text: 'Foo'
end
```

You can access the information by subscribing to the event.

```
ActiveSupport::Notifications.subscribe('render') do |name, start, finish, id, payload|
  name    # => String, name of the event (such as 'render' from above)
  start   # => Time, when the instrumented block started execution
  finish  # => Time, when the instrumented block ended execution
  id      # => String, unique ID for this notification
  payload # => Hash, the payload
end
```

Looking at the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Notifications.html), I can't find anything that would give me the parameters of the render method - `{text: 'foo'}`

What am I missing? Is this possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`render text: 'Foo'` is not a parameter; that's a Rails method that renders content back to the client.

```
ActiveSupport::Notificaitons.instrument("render", text: "foo")
```

is how you would "submit" the values to the notifier.

```
ActiveSupport::Notifications.subscribe("render") do |name, start, finish, id, payload|
  text = payload[:text]
end
```

is how you would reference it in the subscriber.